# Slash commands not syncing to my debug server discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Just started learning how to make discord bots with online videos. Currently, when I try to sync my slash commands to my debug server, the slash commands don't show up.

**Main.py**

```
import settings
import discord
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

logger = settings.logging.getLogger("bot")

def is_owner(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    return str(interaction.user.id) == settings.OWNER_ID

def TableExists(dbcon, table_name):
    dbcur = dbcon.cursor()
    dbcur.execute(f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = '{table_name}'")
    if len(dbcur.fetchall()) >= 1:
        dbcur.close()
        return True
    dbcur.close()
    return False

def run():
    intents = discord.Intents.all()

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", intents=intents)

    @bot.hybrid_command()
    async def sync(ctx):
        logger.info("Syncing slash commands...")
        bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild=ctx.guild)
        commands = await bot.tree.sync(guild=settings.GUILDS_ID)
        logger.info(f"Registered commands: {commands}")
    
    @bot.tree.command(description = "Reload Bot Extensions (Owner only)",)
    @app_commands.check(is_owner)
    async def reload(interaction: discord.Interaction, cog: str = None):
        reloaded = True
        if cog is None:
            logger.info("Attempting to reload extensions...")
            for cog_file in settings.COGS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
                if cog_file != "__init__.py":
                    extension_name = cog_file.name[:-3]
                    try:
                        await bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{extension_name}")
                    except Exception as e:
                        logger.error(f"Failed to reload extension: {e}")
                        reloaded = False
        else:
            try:
                logger.info("Attempting to reload extensions...")
                await bot.reload_extension(f"cogs.{cog.lower()}")
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Failed to reload extension: {e}")
                reloaded = False
        if reloaded:
            logger.info("Extensions reloaded successfully!")
            await interaction.response.send_message("Extensions reloaded", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            logger.info("Extensions failed to reload...")
            await interaction.response.send_message("Extensions failed to reload", ephemeral=True)
        
        bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        bot.tree.clear_commands(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        await bot.tree.sync(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        bot.tree.clear_commands(guild = None)
        await bot.tree.sync()

    @reload.error
    async def say_error(interaction: discord.Integration, error):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have permission to use this command", ephemeral=True)
    
    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        logger.info(f"User: {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})")

        logger.info("Initialising database...")
        conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE Rps")
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE Slap")
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE Ping")
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE Member")
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE Guild")
        if not(TableExists(conn, "Guild")):
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Guild (
                           guildID INT,
                           guildname VARCHAR(255),
                           sfw INT,
                           PRIMARY KEY (guildID)
                           )""")

        if not(TableExists(conn, "Member")):
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Member (
                           memberID INT,
                           guildID INT,
                           membername VARCHAR(255),
                           PRIMARY KEY (memberID, guildID),
                           FOREIGN KEY(guildID) REFERENCES Guild(guildID)
                           )""")
            
        if not(TableExists(conn, "Ping")):
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Ping (
                           pingerID INT,
                           pingerGID INT,
                           count INT,
                           PRIMARY KEY (pingerID),
                           FOREIGN KEY(pingerID) REFERENCES Member(memberID)
                           )""")
            
        if not(TableExists(conn, "Slap")):
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Slap (
                           slapperID INT,
                           slapperGID INT,
                           slappedID INT,
                           count INT,
                           PRIMARY KEY (slapperID, slapperGID),
                           FOREIGN KEY(slapperID, slapperGID, slappedID) REFERENCES Member(memberID, guildID, memberID)
                           )""")
            
        if not(TableExists(conn, "Rps")):
            cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Rps (
                           playerID INT,
                           playerGID INT,
                           won INT,
                           loss INT,
                           draw INT,
                           PRIMARY KEY (playerID, playerGID),
                           FOREIGN KEY(playerID, playerGID) REFERENCES Member(memberID, guildID)
                           )""")
        
        cursor.execute("SELECT guildID FROM Guild")
        guilds = [guildID[0] for guildID in cursor.fetchall()]
        for guild in bot.guilds:
            if guild.id not in guilds:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Guild (guildID, guildname, sfw) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (guild.id, guild.name, 0))
            for member in guild.members:
                cursor.execute("SELECT memberID FROM Member")
                members = [memberID[0] for memberID in cursor.fetchall()]
                if member.id != bot.user.id and member.id not in members:
                    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Member (memberID, guildID, membername) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (member.id, guild.id, member.name))
            conn.commit()
        logger.info("Initialised database!")

        for cog_file in settings.COGS_DIR.glob("*.py"):
            if cog_file != "__init__.py":
                extension_name = cog_file.name[:-3]
                try:
                    logger.info(f"Attempting to load extension: {extension_name}...")
                    await bot.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension_name}")
                    logger.info(f"Extension {extension_name} loaded successfully!")
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"Failed to load extension, {extension_name}: {e}")
        
        bot.tree.copy_global_to(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        bot.tree.clear_commands(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        await bot.tree.sync(guild = settings.GUILDS_ID)
        bot.tree.clear_commands(guild = None)
        await bot.tree.sync()

        conn.close()
        logger.info(f"{bot.user} has booted!")

    bot.run(settings.DISCORD_TOKEN, root_logger = True)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

**Cogs**

```
import asyncio
import random
import discord
import typing
import settings
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
import requests
import typing
from main import logger
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def in_table(cursor, rowID, table, lst):
    for name in lst:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT {rowID} FROM {table} WHERE name = ?", (name,))
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(data) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
        
def member_list(interaction):
    members = []
    for member in interaction.guild.members:
        if member.bot or member.name == interaction.user.name:
            continue
        members.append(member)
    return members

class rpsMenu(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, player, timeout):
        super().__init__(timeout = timeout)
        self.player = player

    accepted = None

    async def disable_all_items(self):
        for item in self.children:
            item.disabled = True
        await self.message.edit(view = self)

    async def on_timeout(self):
        await self.disable_all_items()

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Accept",
                       style = discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def accpet(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        self.accepted = True
        await interaction.response.defer()
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Reject",
                       style = discord.ButtonStyle.red)
    async def reject(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        self.accepted = False
        await interaction.response.defer()
        self.stop()

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction):
        if interaction.user.id != self.player.id:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Hey! This challenge isn\'t for you!", ephemeral = True)
            return False
        return True

class rpsGame(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, player, timeout):
        super().__init__(timeout = timeout)
        self.player = player

    choice = None

    async def disable_all_items(self):
        for item in self.children:
            item.disabled = True
        await self.message.edit(view = self)

    async def on_timeout(self):
        await self.disable_all_items()

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Rock",
                       style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                       emoji = "")
    async def rock(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        self.choice = "rock"
        await interaction.response.defer()
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Paper",
                       style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                       emoji = "")
    async def paper(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        self.choice = "paper"
        await interaction.response.defer()
        self.stop()

    @discord.ui.button(label = "Scissors",
                       style = discord.ButtonStyle.blurple,
                       emoji ="✂")
    async def scissors(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.button):
        self.choice = "scissors"
        await interaction.response.defer()
        self.stop()

    async def interaction_check(self, interaction):
        if interaction.user.id != self.player.id:
            await interaction.response.send_message("Hey! This challenge isn\'t for you!", ephemeral = True)
            return False
        return True

class misc(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    #Member Autocomplete
    async def member_autocompletion(self,
        interaction: discord.Interaction,
        current: str
    ) -> typing.List[app_commands.Choice[str]]:
        data = []
        for player in [member.nick or member.name for member in member_list(interaction)]:
            if current.lower() in player.lower():
                data.append(app_commands.Choice(name = player, value = player))
        return data[:25]
    
    #Answers with "pong"
    @app_commands.command(description = "When you ping it, it'll pong back")
    async def ping(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} initiated ping command")

        conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT count FROM Ping WHERE pingerID = ? AND pingerGID = ?", (interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Ping (pingerID, pingerGID, count) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id, 1))
        else:
            result = result[0]
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Ping SET count = ? WHERE pingerID = ? AND pingerGID = ?", (int(result)+1, interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id))
        conn.commit()
        await interaction.response.send_message("Pong!", ephemeral=True)

        conn.close()
        logger.info(f"User: {self.bot.user} executed ping command")

    #Slaps random person on the server
    @app_commands.command(description = "Slap a random person on the server")
    async def slap(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, item: str = None): # type: ignore
        
        logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} initiated slap command")

        conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        slap_gifs = [
            "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b6/d8/a8/b6d8a83eb652a30b95e87cf96a21e007.gif",
            "https://gifdb.com/images/high/yuruyuri-akari-kyoko-anime-slap-fcacgc0edqhci6eh.gif",
            "https://c.tenor.com/XiYuU9h44-AAAAAC/tenor.gif",
            "https://gifdb.com/images/high/up-close-angry-anime-slap-lf84tjs2sgx8obdr.gif",
            "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-5o0Qi3GjSjs/XQWxWh_PoXI/AAAAAAABiuA/ki1-MN0cHTMqvJQxKpvyLf8nVCCUL0vAwCKgBGAs/s1600/Kimetsu%2Bno%2BYaiba%2B-%2BEpisode%2B11%2B-%2BGirl%2BSlaps%2BZenitsu.gif",
            "https://gifdb.com/images/high/blushing-female-anime-slap-m5wqeyulkwcnqae7.gif",
            "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/a5/1c/71a51cd5b7a3e372522b5011bdf40102.gif",
            "https://reallifeanime.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/akari-slap.gif",
            "https://media.tenor.com/CvBTA0GyrogAAAAC/anime-slap.gif"
        ]
        
        nickname = interaction.user.nick or interaction.user.name
        while True:
            someone = random.choice(interaction.guild.members)
            if someone != interaction.user and someone != self.bot.user:
                break
        if item is None:
            text = f"{nickname} slapped {someone.nick or someone.name}"
        else:
            if item[0].lower() in "aeiou":
                prefix = "an"
            else:
                prefix = "a"
            text = f"{nickname} slapped {someone.nick or someone.name} with {prefix} {item}!"

        cursor.execute("SELECT count FROM Slap WHERE slapperID = ? AND slapperGID = ? AND slappedID = ?", (interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id, someone.id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Slap (slapperID, slapperGID, slappedID, count) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id, someone.id, 1))
            count = 1
        else:
            result = result[0]
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Slap SET count = ? WHERE slapperID = ? AND slapperGID = ? AND slappedID = ?", (int(result)+1, interaction.user.id, interaction.guild.id, someone.id))
            count = int(result)+1
        conn.commit()
        
        slapper_bytes = await interaction.user.display_avatar.read()
        slapper = Image.open(BytesIO(slapper_bytes))

        slap_hand_bytes = urllib.request.urlopen("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DIrx7rsXUAALmv0.jpg")
        slap_hand = Image.open(slap_hand_bytes)
        
        slapped_bytes = await someone.display_avatar.read()
        slapped = Image.open(BytesIO(slapped_bytes))

        slapping = Image.new("RGB", (3*slapper.size[0], slapper.size[1]), (250, 250, 250))
        slapping.paste(slapped, (0, 0))
        slapping.paste(slap_hand, (slapper.size[0], 0))
        slapping.paste(slapper, (2*slapper.size[0], 0))

        slapping_bytes = BytesIO()
        slapping.save(slapping_bytes, format = "PNG")
        slapping_bytes.seek(0)

        embed = discord.Embed(
            color = discord.Colour.og_blurple(),
            description = text,
            title = "Slap-o-tronic has activated!"
        )
        #embed.set_author(name = "Kek", url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wILcnFaO2lk&list=PLESMQx4LeD3N0-KKPPDaToZhBsom2E_Ju&index=22")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = "attachment://slapping.png")
        
        #embed.add_field(name = "slap gif", value = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b6/d8/a8/b6d8a83eb652a30b95e87cf96a21e007.gif", inline = False)
        embed.set_image(url = random.choice(slap_gifs))

        if count > 1:
            back_s = "s"
        else:
            back_s = ""
        embed.set_footer(text = f"{someone.nick or someone.name} has been slapped by {interaction.user} {count} time{back_s}.")

        await interaction.response.defer()
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        await interaction.followup.send(file = discord.File(slapping_bytes, filename = "slapping.png"), embed = embed)

        conn.close()
        logger.info(f"User: {self.bot.user} executed slap command")

    #Rock Paper Scissors against the bot or someone else
    @app_commands.command(description = "Play Rock Paper Scissors")
    @app_commands.autocomplete(player = member_autocompletion)
    async def rps(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, player: str):
        logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} initiated rps command")

        conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        for member in member_list(interaction):
            if member.nick or member.name == player:
                player = member
                break

        embed = discord.Embed(
            colour = discord.Colour.yellow(),
            description = f"<@{interaction.user.id}> has challenged <@{player.id}> to a Rock, Paper, Scissors!",
            title = "A new challenger approaches!"
        )
        embed.set_footer(text = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} has 60 seconds to accept or reject the challenge.")

        view = rpsMenu(player, timeout = 60)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed = embed, view = view)
        message = await interaction.original_response()
        view.message = message
        
        await view.wait()
        await view.disable_all_items()

        if view.accepted is None:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                colour = discord.Colour.red(),
                description = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} did not respond in time...",
                title = "You ran out of time..."
            )
            await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
        elif view.accepted is False:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                colour = discord.Colour.red(),
                description = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} rejected the challenge...",
                title = "Maybe another time..."
            )
            await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                colour = discord.Colour.yellow(),
                description = f"It's currently <@{interaction.user.id}>'s turn.",
                title = "Rock Paper Scissors"
            )
            embed.set_footer(text = f"{interaction.user.nick or interaction.user.global_name} has 60 seconds to choose.")

            view = rpsGame(interaction.user, timeout = 60)
            await message.edit(embed = embed, view = view)
            message = await interaction.original_response()
            view.message = message
            
            await view.wait()
            await view.disable_all_items()

            if view.choice is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    colour = discord.Colour.red(),
                    description = f"{interaction.user.nick or interaction.user.global_name} did not respond in time...",
                    title = "You ran out of time..."
                )
                await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
            else:
                challenger_choice = view.choice

                embed = discord.Embed(
                    colour = discord.Colour.yellow(),
                    description = f"It's currently <@{player.id}>'s turn.",
                    title = "Rock Paper Scissors"
                )
                embed.set_footer(text = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} has 60 seconds to choose.")

                view = rpsGame(player, timeout = 60)
                await message.edit(embed = embed, view = view)
                message = await interaction.original_response()
                view.message = message
                
                await view.wait()
                await view.disable_all_items()

                if view.choice is None:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        colour = discord.Colour.red(),
                        description = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} did not respond in time...",
                        title = "You ran out of time..."
                    )
                    await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
                else:
                    challenged_choice = view.choice
                    beats = {"scissors": "paper", "paper": "rock", "rock": "scissors"}
                    if beats[challenger_choice] == challenged_choice:
                        embed = discord.Embed(
                            colour = discord.Colour.green(),
                            description = f"{interaction.user.nick or interaction.user.global_name} won!",
                            title = "The winner is..."
                        )
                        url = interaction.user.avatar.url
                        winner = interaction.user
                        loser = player
                    elif challenger_choice == challenged_choice:
                        embed = discord.Embed(
                            colour = discord.Colour.green(),
                            description = "No one. It was a draw...",
                            title = "The winner is..."
                        )
                        url = "https://media1.tenor.com/m/T1zotsnaPJsAAAAC/bruh-meme.gif"
                        winner = None
                        loser = None
                    else:
                        embed = discord.Embed(
                            colour = discord.Colour.green(),
                            description = f"{player.nick or player.global_name} won!",
                            title = "The winner is..."
                        )
                        url = player.avatar.url
                        winner = player
                        loser = interaction.user
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url = url)
                    embed.add_field(name = interaction.user.nick or interaction.user.global_name, value = f" picked {challenger_choice}", inline = True)
                    embed.insert_field_at(1, name = player.nick or player.global_name, value = f"picked {challenged_choice}", inline = True)
                    await message.edit(embed = embed, view = None)
                    
                    for person in [interaction.user, player]:
                        cursor.execute("SELECT won, loss, draw FROM Rps WHERE playerID = ? AND playerGID = ?", (person.id, person.id))
                        result = cursor.fetchone()
                        print(result is None)
                        if result is None:
                            if winner == person:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Rps (playerID, playerGID, won, loss, draw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (person.id, person.guild.id, 1, 0, 0))
                            elif loser == person:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Rps (playerID, playerGID, won, loss, draw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (person.id, person.guild.id, 0, 1, 0))
                            else:
                                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Rps (playerID, playerGID, won, loss, draw) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (person.id, person.guild.id, 0, 0, 1))
                        else:
                            result = result[0]
                            if winner == person:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE Rps SET won = ?, loss = ?, draw = ?  WHERE playerID = ? AND playerGID = ?", (person.id, person.guild.id, int(result[0])+1, int(result[0]), int(result[0])))
                            elif loser == person:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE Rps SET won = ?, loss = ?, draw = ?  WHERE playerID = ? AND playerGID = ?", (person.id, person.guild.id, int(result[0]), int(result[0])+1, int(result[0])))
                            else:
                                cursor.execute("UPDATE Rps SET won = ?, loss = ?, draw = ?  WHERE playerID = ? AND playerGID = ?", (person.id, person.guild.id, int(result[0]), int(result[0]), int(result[0])+1))
                        conn.commit()
        
        conn.close()
        logger.info(f"User: {self.bot.user} executed rps command")

    #Make the bot repeat something you type
    @app_commands.command(description = "Make the bot say seomthing you type")
    async def say(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, text: typing.Literal["repeat", "black"]):
        if text == "repeat":
            logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} initiated say: repeat command")
            await interaction.response.send_message(text)
            logger.info(f"User: {interaction.client.user} executed say: repeat command")
        elif text == "black":
            logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} initiated say: black command")

            sentence = text
            
            url = "https://lingojam.com/TotallyNotRacistTranslator"
            page = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html")

            print(soup)

            logger.info(f"User: {interaction.client.user} executed say: black command")

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(misc(bot))
```

```
import settings
import discord
import sqlite3
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands
from main import logger

profanities = set([word.strip() for word in open("badwords.txt", "r").readlines()])

def is_owner(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    return str(interaction.user.id) == settings.OWNER_ID

class callout(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        if message.guild is not None:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
            cursor = conn.cursor()

            cursor.execute("SELECT sfw FROM Guild WHERE guildID = ?", (message.guild.id,))
            sfw = cursor.fetchone()[0]
            if sfw == 1:
                msg = message.content.lower().split(" ")
                if len(set(msg).intersection(profanities)) > 0 and message.author != self.bot.user:
                    await message.add_reaction("")
                    logger.info(f"User: {message.author}, said a bad word!")

            conn.close()

    @app_commands.command(description = "Toggle foul word detection (Owner Only)")
    @app_commands.check(is_owner)
    async def sfw(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        logger.info(f"User: {interaction.user} toggled sfw")

        conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{settings.DBS_DIR}\\boxbot.db")
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        cursor.execute("SELECT sfw FROM Guild WHERE guildID = ?", (interaction.guild.id,))
        sfw = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        if sfw == 1:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Guild SET sfw = ? WHERE guildID = ?", (0, interaction.guild.id))
            await interaction.response.send_message("Foul word detection has been turned off.", ephemeral = True)
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE Guild SET sfw = ? WHERE guildID = ?", (1, interaction.guild.id))
            await interaction.response.send_message("Foul word detection has been turned on.", ephemeral = True)
        conn.commit()

        conn.close()
        logger.info(f"User: {self.bot.user} executed sfw command")

    @sfw.error
    async def sfw_error(interaction: discord.Integration, error):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have permission to use this command", ephemeral=True)

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(callout(bot))
```

I've tried syncing them using both a hybrid command and even putting it within `on_ready` itself but it doesn't seem to be working...

The output for my /sync command returns this: `Registered commands: []`

P.S. The slash commands did work before, however, this issue only arose after I stared adding more commands to my Cogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So randomly it started working, and I can only see 2 obvious reasons that could have caused it

Adding `@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id = *guild ID*))` in front of the app_commands seemed to make is update for the guild in question. **OR** Simply restarting the discord client (i.e. force shutdown the app from task manager or toolsbar) seemed to refresh the cached data

Answer (score 0):

```
 @bot.command()
async def clearcache(ctx):
    bot.command_prefix = "!"  # Change this to your actual command prefix
    await bot.http.clear_application_commands(bot.user.id, bot.token)
    await ctx.send("Command cache cleared.")
```

Run this command, then try syncing again. If you're still having issues, share more details or code so we can help better.

Comment: The command returned this error: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'HTTPClient' object has no attribute 'clear_application_commands'`

I don't believe that the code in the Cogs matter much since they were working before.